# Making Google maps automatically zoom out more when displaying specified location

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I've got a bootstrap website that is using google maps to display a location as the header image.

You can see the webpage here: http://www.tarmastersasphalt.com/contact.asp

The html code in the page is this:

```
<div id="map" class="map img-responsive">
</div>
```

.

The page pulls in these standard bootstrap functions in the footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/gmap/gmap.js"></script>
```

.

and the page also calls in this function:

```
var ContactPage = function () {

    return {

        //Basic Map
        initMap: function () {
            var map;
            $(document).ready(function(){
              map = new GMaps({
                div: '#map',
                lat: 38.9721102,
                lng: -94.1037494
              });

              var marker = map.addMarker({
                lat: 38.9721102,
                lng: -94.1037494,
                title: 'Tar Masters.'
               });
            });
        },

        //Panorama Map
        initPanorama: function () {
            var panorama;
            $(document).ready(function(){
              panorama = GMaps.createPanorama({
                el: '#panorama',
                lat : 38.9721102,
                lng : -94.1037494
              });
            });
        }        

    };
}();
```

.

And then performs this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        ContactPage.initMap();        
    });
</script>
```

.

This all works fine.  What I want to do is to have the google map actually appear more zoomed out when first displayed on the page.  I think you can use something like this `&z=nn` or `,nnz` in the link to accomplish this.

.

For example - if you use a browser and go directly to this URL:

https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/1426+State+Hwy+TT,+Bates+City,+MO+64011,+USA/@38.9555594,-94.1035777,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x87c11502459d838b:0xadf0c711b5a89c2a

you will see the map as it is displayed on my website.  But if you go here:

https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/1426+State+Hwy+TT,+Bates+City,+MO+64011,+USA/@38.9734448,-94.1113454,13z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x87c11502459d838b:0xadf0c711b5a89c2a

you will see the map as I want it to appear on my website.  Notice the use of `,17z` in the first link, and `,13z` in the second link.  (BTW: I also noticed that it seemed to change the coordinate numbers.. not sure what that is all about.)

.

**So my question is as follows:**  Is there any way to tell the gmap function that I want it to be more zoomed out upon first displaying (without having to manually zoom out once it has been displayed)?

I think I have read somewhere that you can add some invisible markers that will force google to zoom out more in order to display all markers in the visable area.. but I am not sure how to accomplish this either.

.

Note: Please view the website on a large screen to see what I am talking about. (I use a static image as the header image when the window size get's small, because the interactiveness of the map doesn't work well with smart phone displays.. you can't scroll past the header image as it takes up the whole viewport, and all you do is move the map around, not scroll down the page.)

.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must define the zoom in the options you pass to GMaps, e.g.:

```
map = new GMaps({
            div: '#map',
            lat: 38.9721102,
            lng: -94.1037494,
            zoom: 10
          });
```

(The default-value is 15)

Comment: Perfect!!!  Thank you so much for the quick response.  Would you also happen to know of a way to shift the marker down the viewing area, so it isn't dead center?

Comment: You may pan the map after the creation of `map`:`map.map.panBy(0,-100);` (the -100 are the pixels downwards from the current center)

Comment: Thx @Dr.Molle, I think that is what I want to do.. but I am not sure where to put the map.map.panBy(0,-100); code - does it go somewhere inside the code I provided in the question?  Can you show me where?

Comment: Thanks!  Works perfectly.  FYI: I put it here:  var marker = map.addMarker({ ... }); map.panBy(15, -130);